# How to set and check session in Coldfusion 11?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am very new to ColdFusion. I am building a very basic system in which I now need to set a session variable, in case of successful login. But I don't know how to set session in ColdFusion or how to check it on application pages.

I searched for solution but could not find satisfactory solution. I need some example in which a session is set in case of login, and destroyed on logout.
I've read about `Application.cfm`, but where this file is located?
This could be a simple question and may be repeating in some ways.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should probably use:

```
Application.cfc
```

You can either use:

```
OnSessionStart
```

In which case you don't need to lock your session variables, as Coldfusion takes care of this. 
If you set your session variable outside of this method, you may need to lock the variable like:

**Before login:**

```
<cfif NOT StructKeyExists(session,"authenticated")>
  <cflock scope="session" timeout="30" type="exclusive">
    <cfset session.authenticated = false />
  </cflock>
</cfif>
```

**New account creation:**

When a user logs in, remember to use something like BCrypt() to hash the password & store in DB. Don't encrypt passwords as these can be unencrypted and this can create a potential security loophole.

https://github.com/tonyjunkes/BCryptCFC

```
<cfset salt = BCrypt.genSalt()>
<cfset hash = BCrypt.hashString("password", salt)>
```

**Login validation:**

After a user has logged in, use BCrypt() to check whether the clear text password matches the password hash in your DB:

```
<cfset BCrypt.checkString("password", hash)>
```

Also check that the 'username' [e-mail] matches...

If BCrypt() validation is successful, then set your 'session' variable:

```
<cflock scope="session" timeout="30" type="exclusive">
  <cfset session.authenticated = true />
</cflock>
```

This is a very basic implementation of how the login should work, but it gives you an idea of how to get started.

Another tip, is that, if you are locking your 'session' variables, then instead of having to continually use:

```
<cflock>
```

When reading from the session, it would be advisable to convert your 'sesssion' variable into the 'variables' scope, like:

```
<cflock scope="session" timeout="10" type="readOnly">
  <cfset variables.lckauthenticated = session.authenticated />
</cflock>
```

You can then use:

```
variables.lckauthenticated
```

Outside of the `<cflock>` tag.

Now, there is some debate as to whether you need to lock 'session' variables, but my rule, and one that is recommended in Adobe's Official Documentation, is to lock 'session' variables, if you are reading & writing to them outside of onSessionStart.

Then, when your user logs out, just set:

```
<cflock scope="session" timeout="30" type="exclusive">
  <cfset session.authenticated = false />
</cflock>
```

You can then use this flag, to determine what is displayed to your user. 
I usually set several 'session' variables during a successful login, like:

```
session.userid
session.roleid
```

There are other things like 'session' rotation, which help to safeguard your session, but these are more advanced topics for another post...